# Oracle Gobal Temp table issue

Tags: oracle

I am using `JdbcTemplate` and Oracle stored procedure. In oracle store procedure I have a select query in which I have IN clause like `'IN (SELECT ID FROM GLOBAL_TEMP_TABLE)'`.
And the definition of **temp table** is `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`.

However, when I am calling **stored procedure** from java it give me more records than I expected, seems temp table is storing data from previous session. Need your help.

Comment: `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` will preserve data until the end of the session.Might be session might not have closed after the operation

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access data from a previous or other session when you select rows from a global temporary table.
There are 2 options:

1. Your session is not new
2. It's not a temporary table

Keep in mind if you use `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` you have to delete the rows yourself. The data is kept until the session ends.

To find out if your session is still the same, query is:

```
select sid,serial,logon_time from v$session
```

and write it to a log file.

Comment: Could this be an issue with the session coming from a shared-pool ?

Comment: yes thanks, this is also possible. If a session comes from a connection pool then the session might not be new. Then the temporary table should be created with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`. If this is not an option you have to store some session information in the temporary table to be able to distinguish between different sessions.

Answer (score 1):

[Without looking at any code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is hard to tell.

Yet, the symptoms you describe might only be caused because you are still accessing your data from the *same session*.

From [Oracle-Base: Global Temporary Tables (GTT)](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php#creation):

- The `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` clause indicates that the data should be deleted at the **end of the transaction**.
- the `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` clause indicates that rows should be preserved until the **end of the session**.

That is, in your case, you need to *close* the session to clear the data.